# Многопоточность в автоматизации тестирования

Tags: java, selenium, maven, junit

Всем привет. Пытаюсь решить проблему с параллельным запуском автотестов. Судя по allure репортам, выполняются они в несколько потоков, однако при закрытии сессии браузера в одном тесте в аннотации @AfterEach, в остальных тестах вылетает NoSuchSessionException. Использую WebDriverFactory и PageObject, статики убрал везде где мог, а сам драйвер обернул в ThreadLocal. После этих действий проблема все еще не была решена.

Тестовые классы наследуются от baseTest, где и происходит вызов драйвера, вместе с @BeforeEach и @AfterEach.

Классы запускаю в same_thread, методы в concurrent.

Прошу помощи и по возможности посоветуйте различного материала для изучения использования Selenium, паттернов, многопоточности.

BaseTest:

```
public class BaseTest {
private WebDriverFactory wbf = new WebDriverFactory();
public ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver;
private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(BaseTest.class);

String os = System.getProperty("os.name");

Random random = new Random();
//Необходимы постоянно новые значение
String phoneNumber = String.format("%09d", random.nextInt(999999999));
String emailName = String.format("%09d", random.nextInt(999999999));
String email = emailName + "@mail.ru";
String seriesDoc = String.format("%04d", random.nextInt(9999));
String numberDoc = String.format("%06d", random.nextInt(999999));
String snils = "39638621635";
String testPhotoPath = getTestPhotoPath();
String testPhotoHugePath = getTestPhotoHugePath();
String testPdfPath = getTestPdfPath();

public ClientBuilder builder = new ClientBuilder(
        new String(this.phoneNumber),
        new String(this.email),
        new String(this.seriesDoc),
        new String(this.numberDoc),
        new String(this.snils),
        new String(this.testPhotoPath),
        new String(this.testPhotoHugePath),
        new String(this.testPdfPath)
);

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if (os.contains("Windows")) {
        this.testPhotoPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("testphotopathwindows");
        this.testPhotoHugePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("testhugephotowindows");
        this.testPdfPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("testpdfwindows");
    } else {
        this.testPhotoPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("testphotopathubuntu");
        this.testPhotoHugePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("testhugephotoubuntu");
        this.testPdfPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("testpdfubuntu");
    }
    //-Dbrowser
    String browser = System.getProperty("browser", "chrome").toLowerCase();
    //-Dstrategy
    String strategy = System.getProperty("strategy", "NORMAL").toUpperCase();
    driver = new ThreadLocal<>();
    driver.set(wbf.getDriver(BrowserName.fromString(browser), StrategyName.fromString(strategy)));
    logger.info(driver.hashCode());
    logger.info("Драйвер запущен");
}

@AfterEach
public void setDown() {
    logger.info(driver.hashCode());
    if(getDriver() != null) {
        getDriver().quit();
        logger.info("Драйвер остановлен");
    }
    driver.remove();
}

public String getTestPhotoPath() {
    if (os.contains("Windows")) {
        return System.getProperty("user.dir") + PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("testphotopathwindows");
    } else {
        return System.getProperty("user.dir") + PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("testphotopathubuntu");
    }
}

public String getTestPhotoHugePath() {
    if (os.contains("Windows")) {
        return System.getProperty("user.dir") + PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("testhugephotowindows");
    } else {
        return System.getProperty("user.dir") + PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("testhugephotoubuntu");
    }
}

public String getTestPdfPath() {
    if (os.contains("Windows")) {
        return System.getProperty("user.dir") + PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("testpdfwindows");
    } else {
        return System.getProperty("user.dir") + PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("testpdfubuntu");
    }
}

public WebDriver getDriver() {
    return driver.get();
}
```

WebDriverFactory:

```
public class WebDriverFactory {
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(WebDriverFactory.class);

protected WebDriver driver;

public WebDriver getDriver(BrowserName name, StrategyName strategy) {
    switch (name) {
        case CHROME:
            ChromeBrowser chromeBrowser = new ChromeBrowser();
            logger.info("Драйвер для браузера Chrome");
            driver = chromeBrowser.getDriver(strategy);
            return driver;
        case EDGE:
            EdgeBrowser edgeBrowser = new EdgeBrowser();
            logger.info("Драйвер для браузера Edge");
            driver = edgeBrowser.getDriver(strategy);
            return driver;
        case FIREFOX:
            FirefoxBrowser firefoxBrowser = new FirefoxBrowser();
            logger.info("Драйвер для браузера FireFox");
            driver = firefoxBrowser.getDriver(strategy);
            return driver;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Некорректное имя браузера");
    }
}
}
```

BasePage:

```
public abstract class BasePage {
protected WebDriver driver;

public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;

    WaitFor.initWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(40), Duration.ofMillis(10000));

    JSExecutor.initJS(driver);
}

public abstract void success(Client client);

public abstract void success();
```

}

```
public class RegistrationStepOnePage extends BasePage {
public RegistrationStepOnePage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}


private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(RegistrationStepOnePage.class);

//----Локаторы----
//Поле "Фамилия"
String surNameXpath = "//input[@id='surname']";
//
//Методы 
public RegistrationStepOne textBoxSurnameSetValue(String surname) {
//
}
```

ChromeBrowser:

```
public class ChromeBrowser {

public RemoteWebDriver getDriver(StrategyName strategy) {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--incognito");
    options.addArguments("--start-fullscreen");
    options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
    switch (strategy) {
        case NORMAL:
            options.setCapability(CapabilityType.PAGE_LOAD_STRATEGY, PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
            break;
        case NONE:
            options.setCapability(CapabilityType.PAGE_LOAD_STRATEGY, PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
            break;
        case EAGER:
            options.setCapability(CapabilityType.PAGE_LOAD_STRATEGY, PageLoadStrategy.EAGER);
            break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Неправильное имя стратегии. Используйте NORMAL/EAGER/NONE");
    }
    options.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);

    return new ChromeDriver(options);
}
```

}

junit-platform-properties:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy = custom
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.custom.class = resources.CustomStrategyParallelism
```

CustomStrategyParallelism:

```
public class CustomStrategyParallelism  implements ParallelExecutionConfiguration, ParallelExecutionConfigurationStrategy {
@Override
public int getParallelism() {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public int getMinimumRunnable() {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public int getMaxPoolSize() {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public int getCorePoolSize() {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public int getKeepAliveSeconds() {
    return 30;
}

@Override
public ParallelExecutionConfiguration createConfiguration(final ConfigurationParameters configurationParameters) {
    return this;
}
```

}

1 из тестов:

```
public class PageOneFieldsTest extends BaseTest {
private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PageOneFieldsTest.class);

@Test
//Тест ввода неверной фамилии
public void illegalSurnameTest() {
    try {
        logger.info("Запущен тест ввода неверной фамилии");
        Client client = startPageSuccess();

        RegistrationStepOnePage regOnePage = new RegistrationStepOnePage(getDriver());
        regOnePage.textBoxSurNameSetValue("Testov")
                .textBoxNameSetValue(PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("name"))
                .textBoxFatherNameSetValue(PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("fathername"))
                .textBoxEmailSetValue(client.getEmail())
                .textBoxPhoneNumberSetValue(client.getPhoneNumber())
                .buttonSmsButtonClick()
                .textBoxSmsCodeSetValue(PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("smscode"))
                .checkBoxTermsOfUseSetChecked()
                .illegalNamesErrorAssert()
                .assertContinueNotClickable();
    } finally {
        Screenshoter.makeScreenshot("png", "illegalSurnameTest", getDriver());
    }
}
}
```

Такой стектрейс зачастую выпадает:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'
System info: host: 'WS-CHERNECOV', ip: '192.168.3.65', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '16.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, findElement {using=xpath, value=//div[input[@id='email']]//div[@id='0item']}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 96.0.4664.45, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab46..., userDataDir: C:\Users\CHERNE~1\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:60606}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:60606/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 96.0.4664.45, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:559)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:383)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:375)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
    at helpers.WaitFor.visibilityOfElementLocated(WaitFor.java:31)
    at web.pages.elements.Button.click(Button.java:14)
    at web.pages.client.registration.RegistrationStepOnePage.textBoxEmailSetValue(RegistrationStepOnePage.java:116)
    at tests.client.registration.PageOneFieldsTest.emptyFatherNameTest(PageOneFieldsTest.java:211)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService$ExclusiveTask.compute(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:185)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:194)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:295)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1665)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1598)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

Бывает и такой:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'
System info: host: 'WS-CHERNECOV', ip: '192.168.3.65', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '16.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [ebe6219244ab24d7bee1509c4d23cf5b, findElement {using=xpath, value=//div[input[@id='email']]//div[@id='0item']}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 96.0.4664.45, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab46..., userDataDir: C:\Users\CHERNE~1\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:60758}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:60758/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 96.0.4664.45, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: ebe6219244ab24d7bee1509c4d23cf5b

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:583)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:383)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:375)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
    at helpers.WaitFor.visibilityOfElementLocated(WaitFor.java:31)
    at web.pages.elements.Button.click(Button.java:14)
    at web.pages.client.registration.RegistrationStepOnePage.textBoxEmailSetValue(RegistrationStepOnePage.java:116)
    at tests.client.registration.PageOneFieldsTest.illegalFatherNameTest(PageOneFieldsTest.java:75)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService$ExclusiveTask.compute(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:185)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:194)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:295)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1665)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1598)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:55312
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:51)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:559)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:55312
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:179)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:108)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:55312
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:669)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:944)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на ruSO. Вместо словесного описания кода, добавьте сам код (методы с их детальной логикой кликания и т.д. имеет смысл сократить), а вот инфраструктуру, т.е. логику инициализации/деинициализации, параллельного запуска и т.д. нужно показать. Из текстового описания мало что понятно. Далее, нужно включить стектрейс когда падает.

Comment: Проблема так и не решена)